# ¿Como se puede hacer un casting en c para transformar *void a un array?

Tags: c

Yo aprendo c por mi cuenta y hace poco descubrí como funcionaban los castings de datos y tengo entendido que es asi:

```
int numero = (int)variable;
```

el problema es que al intentar poner como tipo de dato un array no me deja y me da un error. Este es mi código por si os sirve para entender mi problema:

```
void *traspaso(void*);

void *traspaso(void *parametros)
{
    struct clientes cliente[2];
    cliente= *(struct clientes[])parametros;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nunca me he planteado esta cuestión, pero aplicando un poco de lógica creo que no se puede, ya que una estructura puede tener la estructura (valga la redundancia) que el programador desee. Cuando haces un `cast` a una variable estás por así decirlo truncándola a una estructura de datos definidas. Lo que no entiendo es que si `parametros` va a ser una estructura de tipo `clientes`, ¿por qué no la declaras como tal?. Lo que sí sé que se puede hacer es asignar una variable el valor de una variable que forma la estructura y así hacer el `cast` individual de una variable en concreto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es normal que te de error, porque estás haciendo un disparate.

---

Cuando en [c](/questions/tagged/c) defines una formación<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática<sup>2</sup> se crea un espacio de memoria para todos los elementos de la formación; esta formación no puede cambiar el lugar al que apunta porque tiene el tamaño y espacio reservado definidos en tiempo de compilación, así que cuando haces esto:

```
struct clientes cliente[2];
cliente= *(struct clientes[])parametros;
```

Le estás diciendo al compilador: "*¿Recuerdas aquella formación de clientes que te pedí con dos elementos? ¡olvídalo! ahora quiero que esa formación sea otra cosa*", lo cuál no tiene sentido para el compilador y responde quejándose. Lo que en realidad querías hacer es esto:

```
void *traspaso(void *parametros)
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^ <--- El parámetro recibido es una formación
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct clientes cliente[2];

    traspaso(cliente);
    //       ^^^^^^^ <--- pasar la formación A el puntero a void

    return 0;
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. Los nombres de tus tipos son incorrectos, si tienes una estructura que almacena un cliente, el nombre de la estructura debe ser singular y si tienes una formación que almacena clientes, el nombre de la formación debe ser plural:

   ```
   struct cliente clientes[2];
   //     ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Dos clienteS (plural)
   //        \
   //         \___ Sólo un cliente (singular)
   ```
2. Pasar un tipo a puntero a `void` elimina toda la información del tipo, esta operación sólo es válida si sabes muy bien qué es lo que recibes en el puntero a `void`. En general es mejor evitar hacer eso porque un puntero a `void` puede recibir cualquier cosa, mientras que (por ejemplo) un puntero a `struct cliente` sólo puede recibir `struct cliente`.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

<sup>2</sup>Memoria automática es aquella que no se pide con `malloc`.